# Run cron Tasks at Midnight on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have created my cron task to run every day at 00:00. However, I don't understand how this works.

I have   `if Time.now.hour == 0` in my `cron.rake` but I don't understand if I need to setup the cron:daily addon at midnight?

Anyone care to explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku's cron:daily addon will only run the cron rake task every day at the time you activate the addon. So the condition in your rake task won't do anything. Just deactivate the cron addon, wait until midnight and then turn it on (probably via command line would be easiest). It's a little annoying that you have to do it this way, but that's what their docs say.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron#frequently-asked-questions - Scroll to the bottom.

Comment: or create the cron and email support - they will happily move the cron job for you.

Comment: Actually, I've asked before. The CSR I got told me to do it manually.